# My line graph flattens when adding in axis names from date table

Tags: powerbi, linegraph

I am trying to graph my table in a double line graph.  When I use data just from this table it graphs correctly:

[image]

[image]

As soon as I drop in the Month name from my date table, it flattens the line to a count.

[image]

I don't see where I can change this.  Also, the relationships of the tables are fine as I can line up the month number from my data set and it matches the correct month name.  Please help!

Comment: I just doubled checked and my linked columns are both numbers and it is still not working correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't call that first chart correct. it is sorted by value rather than by month. Is the date table correctly related to the month column? Does the data span more than 12 months?  As a new user please read this carefully: Edit your question and provide more detail. Do not do that in comments. Leave a comment when you've updated your question.